# Here document not executed in subshell in crontab

Tags: bash, cron, sftp, heredoc

I have a script that works well from the prompt but not from crontab. The only thing that is broken is a here document ignored in a subshell in the script. The script uses psftp. Here is the code:

/home/batch/myscript.sh:

```
(
cd /home/downloaded/csv/
psftp -pw passw0rd -P 1234 user@someftp.com << EOF
cd outgoing
mget *.csv
EOF
) | tee /home/batch/logs/mylog.log | mail -s "Mail subject" "me@mycompany.com"
```

crontab -e:

```
45 10 * * * /bin/sh /home/batch/myscript.sh
```

OK - Mail when launched from prompt:

```
Remote working directory is /
psftp> Remote directory is now /outgoing
psftp> *.csv: nothing matched
psftp> quit
```

KO - Mail when launched from crontab:

```
Remote working directory is /
psftp> quit
```

Google does not provide a lot of help. I have tried several EOF syntaxes as it seems a common problem of here documents, but I don't think it comes from this. It might have to do with some kind of nesting level with regards to crontab, is there such a thing?

Best regards

Comment: Try removing the space after `<<`?

Comment: @tripleee I just tried removing the space, it did not change the problem. Crontab KO, Prompt OK.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, problem solved:

The user crontab uses to execute the script is different. What happened is that the sftp's key was not registered for this user. This cause a prompt asking to register the key, which was not answered by my script.

I connected as the user it uses, psftp'd and registred the key.